# Nginx sub_filter for headers

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to use nginx proxy_pass before different applications which run on their own port.

so i.e. I have

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/self-signed.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/self-signed.key;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1111;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2222;
    }
}
```

However the problem is the applications itself have redirects in them which causes the /app1/ or /app2/ to disappear.

i.e. a 302 get /page1 will become https://example.com/page1 instead of https://example.com/app1/page1

So basically whenever someone is at a /app1/* page to always prefix /app1/.

and it would be really great if this doesn't happen when this is actually the full domain name so it's possible to load resources from a /app2/ url in a /app1/ page

Is there a way I can fix with Nginx config or can I only fix this in the application itself?

EDIT:

I found that Nginx has a function called sub_filter.

This replaced strings in the body of the response.

so:
app returns: 200 "hello world!"

```
//nginx
sub_filter "world" "moon";
```

then the browser will display "hello moon!"

However I also need to do this for 302 redirects.

Is there a "sub_filter equivalent" for headers?

EDIT2:

As Ivan suggested probably proxy redirect should do the trick, but it's not changing anything.
my nginx code is:

```
location /app1/ {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; # no compression allowed or next won't work
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000/ /app1/; #also tried full domain
}
```

As for the app I'm testing this with a simple Flask app like this:

```
@app.route('/')  
def hello_world(): 
    return redirect("http://localhost:5000/testing", code=302)
```

and the browser response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 06 Nov 2019 15:56:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://localhost:5000/testing
```

Comment: What happens if you try `proxy_pass http://localhost:1111/app1/;` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:2222/app2/;`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky It returns a 404 because there isn't a /app1/ path in the app.

Comment: What are these redirects looks like? Are them 3xx HTTP codes or they are `href`'s in response body?

Comment: @IvanShatsky these are 302 http codes. The href's can be done with the sub_filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive for your case:

```
proxy_redirect / /app1/;
```

and

```
proxy_redirect / /app2/;
```

Remove any `proxy_redirect off;` directive because it cancels the effect of all `proxy_redirect` directives on the same level.

Comment: I think you're correct that it should be done with proxy_redirect. However nothing has been changed. I'll put my code edits in the question.

Comment: @user3605780 remove `proxy_redirect off;` directive and try this one

Comment: Thank you! I have been tackling a problem with ports - I am behind NAT and have no control over 80, using only a non-standard port for https, and my app was sending out redirects to 80. Your suggestion pointed me to the right solution of rewriting the response headers: `proxy_redirect http://$host/ https://$host:1443/;` Note this is a dirty solution not good for production use - for that you obviously should control 80 (or rather all ports and other important aspects of your server).